# query no PHP vem vazia mas no SQL Server tem resultado

Tags: php, sql-server, query, codeigniter

Boa tarde, tenho um procedimento para executar no sql server, se eu executar diretamente no SQL ela executa normalmente, me retornando a linha esperada como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas quando executo no codeIgniter 3 (php) ele não da erro mas também não traz a minha row.

controller:

```
 $result = $this->posvendas->totalPassagens([getCodeLocal($local), date('Y-m-01 00:00:00'), date('Y-m-d 23:59:59')]); // Não esta retornando a consulta
         echo '<prev>';
         print_r($result);
```

Model:

```
     public function totalPassagens(array $array)
{
    $params = [
        3562,
        0,
        '2020-10-01 00:00:00',
        '2020-10-30 23:59:59'
    ];

    $sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON exec whRelOSTotalizarResultadoAgendamento ?, ?, ?, ?";
    $data = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    return $data->result_array();
}
```

Saida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não entendo o motivo de não em retornar os resultados

Comment: A resposta respondeu a sua duvida?

Answer (score 2):

Para ter êxito em enviar valores para uma `Stored Procedure` tem que passar um `array` de parâmetros, exemplo mínimo:

***Tabela:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Stored Procedure***

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_INSERT_SOURCES]   
    @Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Created Date,
    @Status Bit
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Sources(Name, Created, Status) VALUES(@Name, @Created, @Status);
    SELECT * FROM Sources WHERE Sources.Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

esse `script` tem a função de inserir novo registro, recuperar e enviar o registro inserido para o código.

---

*Como utilizar isso tudo agora com o* [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter)?

***Código exemplo***:

```
$params = [
    'StackOverFlow',
    '1992-01-01',
    0
];
$sql = 'EXEC SP_INSERT_SOURCES ?, ?, ?';
$this->db->query($sql, $params);
```

nos parâmetros coloca-se o sinal de interrogação (`?`) que refere-se a quantidade de variáveis dessa `Stored` `Procedure`.

No seu código basicamente:

```
public function totalPassagens()
{
    $params = [
        3562,
        0
        '2020-10-01 00:00:00',
        '2020-10-30 23:59:59'
    ];
    $sql = "exec whRelOSTotalizarResultadoAgendamento ?, ?, ?, ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

***Observação:*** *respeito o tipo de informação enviada para a base de dados, ou seja, como cada campo está configurado*.

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Call stored procedure from php codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33178552/6797930)
- [Using MSSQL stored procedures with codeigniter](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-46158.html)

Comment: eu fiz exatamente como você me falou, passando parâmetros, mas o resultado é o mesmo, eu coloquei exatamente a consulta inteira sem parâmetros para me certificar que a mesma não esta passando valor errado e causando erro, mas o problema é retornar os valores

Comment: Toda essa resposta é testada e avaliada por mim porque são códigos que auxiliam não só você mas, todos, você que está fazendo algo de errado, e outra coisa qual é o erro? ou você não mexer em PHP é iniciante? @LEANDRODASILVA

Comment: sou iniciante sim, posso apagar essa pergunta? ou a outra, eu achei que a outra está mais completa! vou editar a outra!

Comment: Apagar é descredito simplesmente ninguém vai ficar respondendo os seus questionamentos @LEANDRODASILVA porque essa responde a sua nova questão.

Comment: Fiz exatamente como falou, estou tomando o mesmo erro, não pode ser erro de sintaxe do sql pois em outro teste ele foi e no proprio sqlserver funciona, não poderia ser a forma te retornar os valores?

Comment: Olha novamente o exemplo do método `totalPassagens()` que está na resposta e teste novamente @LEANDRODASILVA

Comment: Sim, editei minha pergunta, infelizmente estou a tomar o mesmo erro, o engraçado é que e um arquivo PHP qualquer fiz um teste e foi, apenas no CI3 não trás o resultado!

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, consegui resolver da seguinte maneira, dentro da procedure coloquei o SET NOCOUNT ON; após o begin ao invés de colocar antes do comando exec) poderia colocar o codigo sql aqui mas são mais de 240 linhas acredito que não vem ao caso agora:

```
begin  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
```