# Call to a member function result() on bool

Tags: sql-server, query, pdo, codeigniter-3

Estou tentando trazer resultados de uma `Stored Procedure` no `CodeIgniter`, no banco traz o resultado normalmente mas no `CodeIgniter` trás esse erro:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no meu `model` está assim:

```
public function totalPassagens(array $array)
{
    $sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON exec whRelOSTotalizarResultadoAgendamento 3562, ?, ?, ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

e no meu `controller` apenas para dar a saída fiz assim:

```
$result = $this->posvendas->totalPassagens([getCodeLocal($local), 
      date('Y-m-01 00:00:00'), 
      date('Y-m-d 23:59:59')]); // Não esta retornando a consulta
echo '<prev>';
print_r($result);
```

Se eu tirar o SET NOCOUNT ON da frente do exec ele não da erro mas não me trás o resultado esperado e sim um array vazio, então fiz o teste em um arquivo qualquer com a sequinte consulta :

```
try {
      $Conexao    = ConexaoTS::getConnection();
      $infoQuery  = $Conexao->query("SET NOCOUNT ON  EXEC 
       whRelOSTotalizarResultadoAgendamento 
       @CodigoEmpresa=3562, @CodigoLocal= ?, @DaDataAgenda= ?, 
     @AteDataAgenda= ?");
      
      $info       = $infoQuery->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    
      echo $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    
echo '<prev>';
print_r($info);
```

fiz exatamente a mesma consulta e o resultado foi esse :

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, trouxe os resultados, mas no `CodeIgniter` não me trás nada, já tentei colocar `result_array()`, `get()`, `result()` mas estou tomando o mesmo ***erro***.

Comment: Porque está insistindo da maneira errada? inclusive é duplicata da sua anterior

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [query no PHP vem vazia mas no SQL Server tem resultado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/481138/query-no-php-vem-vazia-mas-no-sql-server-tem-resultado)

Comment: Porque da insistência de fazer errado?

Comment: poderia apagar a pergunta anterior mas pode ajudar outras pessoas, criei uma nova para passar mais informações que pode ser uteis. mas como eu disse fiz exatamente como falou e o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: No seu model, `$this->db->query($sql)` está retornando `false`, o que indica que o SQL está falhando. O que acontece se executá-lo direto no banco de dados?

Comment: Apagar a pergunta que está certa? apagar por simples capricho seu? a comunidade aqui pensa diferente, eu dei para você um parte técnica que muitos erram!

Comment: @Woss ele está usando paramentro param1 dentro da SQL e não é assim que faz ... já escrevi uma resposta para ele sobre essa questão ele continua errando ... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/481138/query-no-php-vem-vazia-mas-no-sql-server-tem-resultado

Comment: @Woss esta executando corretamente, ele traz valores certos, novic eu editei essa conforme você explicou e esta retornando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Esse erro *Call member result on bool* é comum de ocorrer quando há erros de sintaxe na consulta, result set retorna `false` e o programador não realiza nenhum teste de validação nesse result set e o tenta utilizar assim mesmo.

Comment: Poderia me explicar como seria a forma correta? lembrando que no proprio sql funciona e naquele outro teste também, apenas no CI3 não estar funcionando (Sou iniciante PHP)

Comment: Não tem como mostrar, o erro está em outra parte pois a pergunta não mostra informações suficientes para apontar o culpado.

Comment: tem o controller, model, e a saida, oque mais precisa?

Comment: A parte do código que gera o erro pois não está ai. Tenta a mesma consulta em php puro se passar provavelmente é problema com o CodeIgniter, se também não passar pode com o driver sql.

Comment: Eu fiz no PHP puro, ele me trouxe corretamente a mesma consulta! usando o fetchAlll

Comment: O code igniter está corrompido. Ou mal configurado. Mal instalado. Se ter acesso ao sistema não dá para ser categórico, mas é nessa direção.

Comment: troquei a pasta system e ainda sim esta dando erro, baixei novamente e coloquei no xampp, creio ser difícil estar mal instalado visto que é apenas executar! Ou simplesmente não esta instável

Comment: Ai não posso ajudá-lo, só inspecionando o seu sistema. Pelo menos você já tem um rumo.

Comment: Eu fiz uma pesquisa rápida e a instalação manual do CodeIgniter é passivel de gerar conflitos. A instalação pelo composer é mais tranquila mais ainda pode gerar conflitos em caso de atualização.